# Python using string in dict() key?

Tags: python, dictionary

Let say I have this base dictionary:

```
main = {'a': 10}
```

Then I have two other dictionaries which use `main` as starting point like this:

```
some_new_dict1 = dict(main, b=20, some_other_key=100)
some_new_dict2 = dict(main, c=20, some_other_key2=200)
```

But the thing is for `b` and for `c` keys, those are not fixed. It depends on other values.

In my case to evaluate what kind of key to assign to which dictionary is done like this:

```
some_map = {True: 'b', False: 'c'}

# Evaluate if its true or false

answer = something > 0 # something is variable that changes. 
#It can be greater than zero or lower than zero (but not zero).

dict1_key, dict2_key = some_map[answer], some_map[not answer]
```

Now I have these keys in string form, but I don't see how can I assign it through `dict`. If its even possible.

So now I'm doing this:

```
some_new_dict1 = dict(main, some_other_key=100)
some_new_dict1[dict1_key] = 20
# Same for another dict
```

So basically I need to create dictionary and then update it with that one key/value pair even though I know that key/value pair before creating that dictionary. Is there some better way?

Comment: What you are doing is probably the most readable way to do this. You *could* do `some_new_dict1 = dict([(dict1_key, 20), ("some_other_key", 100)] + main.items())`, but is this really worth it?

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to use the `update` method?

Comment: I didn't get the question, if you already know the key/value, why not add it to the dictionnary at its creation? `some_new_dict1 = dict(main, some_other_key=100, dict1_key = 20)`

Comment: @TomásGlaría `some_other_key` is a variable for e.g. either `b` or `c`.

Comment: You cannot really do this in a single line. The solution you have is by far the best way to do this.

Comment: Another vote for "please stick with your current approach".

Comment: Fair enough. If there is nothing better, I guess I'll keep it that way.

Comment: @poke: got it, I now realize the one line only works for string values, no variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
main = {'a': 5}
dict_key1 = 'test_key'
dict_val1 = 5

some_new_dict = dict(main, other_key=5, **{dict_key1: dict_val1})
```

Although, I find the two step way you use now more readable, so I think it's better.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to opt for readability you can use copy, and perhaps also pack your mapping into the line:

```
some_new_dict1 = main.copy()
some_new_dict1[some_other_key] = 100
some_new_dict1['b' if answer else 'c'] = 20
```

By the way your comment `#It can be greater than zero or lower than zero (but not zero).` is false for your dict2_key. `[not answer]` includes zero, if it makes a difference for the logic of your programme.

Comment: Well yeah it includes, but variable `something` is never `0`, so it does not matter.